# Open PDF in new tab with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

I am trying to open a PDF sitting on our sever in a new window when a button is clicked. I am using the `window.open()` function in javascript to try and achieve this. When I click the button, a new tab opens, but it is an about:blank tab. Here is my ASP.NET markup for the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="BTN_OpenPDF" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TicketNum").ToString()%>' OnClientClick='openPDF(this);'/>
```

And here is the javascript code that I am trying to execute:

```
function openPDF(element) {
        var text = element.value;

        window.open('Z:/Ticket Scans/' + text + '.pdf');
    }
```

I am dynamically setting the text of the button to retrieve the ticket number and this works fine. When I step through the debugger I can tell that the file path is correct, but the pdf still does not open.

I am using ASP.NET, C#, and Chrome.

Edit: From doing some research I believe that this may be a Chrome security issue. When using an anchor tag instead of the Javascript:

```
<a target="-blank" href="z:\Ticket Scans\<%#Eval("TicketNum") %>.pdf></a>
```

I get an error in the debugger saying: `Now allowed to load local resource`. But when I run the app in IE11 it works perfectly fine.

Comment: `Z:` is probably the drive on your server, but the user probably don't have direct access to your server and needs a URL instead ?

Comment: the `Z:` drive is a mapped network drive on all workstations on our network. Forgive me, as I am not an IT guru. Would I need to use the server IP address directly?

Comment: Why not use `<a target='_blank' href='path'>text</a>`?

Comment: @Amy when I use the markup you supplied I get the error `Not allowed to load local resource` in the debugger

Comment: @Amy It seems that this may be a chrome issue. I have tested in IE11 and it is working just fine.

Comment: Try `Z:///Ticket Scans/' + text + '.pdf`

Comment: @guest271314 I gave that a try and still doesn't load. I think that I have pin pointed it to a Chrome security issue. It works in IE11

Comment: Try opening chrome with `--allow-access-from-files` flag set , see http://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent/

Comment: It's looking like this may be the answer. Will this reset every time Chrome updates? Also, I am going to have to changes these flags on every workstation, am I not?

Comment: @ChaseErnst Can either adjust launcher , or icon with link to command that launches chrome , to include flags permanently ; or launch chrome from command-line with flags specified for that particular browsing session , which would not change launcher flags . Launcher command should not change when chrome updates

Comment: I understand what needs to be done: I need to modify the local file access flag of chrome, but I have never really worked with the command prompt (I know!!). I don't really understand what that tutorial you linked me is saying. How do I modify the executable chrome application?

Comment: @guest271314 I would like to create this icon for permanent use.

Answer (score 2):

> would like to create this icon for permanent use.

Try adjusting command for launching chrome at properties of launcher icon , adding `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag

`/path/to/chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: Hmm I think I just figured it out. It is exactly like you have posted.

Once I have launched the application I just create a desktop icon for this?

Comment: @ChaseErnst Create , or adjust existin program launcher icon (shortcut) , include flags in command that launches chrome in properties of icon launcher before launching chrome

Comment: Yes, I have created the new icon that I want to modify. I have launched the new chrome in cmd using this: `start chrome.exe -allow-file-access-from-files` and this works properly. How do I make this permanent though? Sorry I don't quite understand. I am new to this.

Comment: @ChaseErnst Launcher should be permanent if icon is how chrome is normally launched ; see also http://superuser.com/questions/513561/windows-8-keeps-removing-some-start-screen-shortcuts-i-make?rq=1 , http://superuser.com/questions/807560/create-program-launch-icon-or-shortcut-on-windows-8-desktop

Comment: So just starting the executable with the above command will make the flag stay permanent?

Comment: Yes that is command that actually launches program ; if valid flags provided , chrome / chromium should run with specified flags set. To confirm this , can open `chrome://version` and review `Command Line` section , which should list set flags for session

Comment: I tried what you said, and I still get the error message in the debugger. Can we move this to the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96484/discussion-between-chase-ernst-and-guest271314).